# How to connect Twilio python program to local server?

Tags: android, python, flask, twilio

So I saw this amazing hackathon project, and I would like to test it out.

Here is the link for your reference: https://github.com/ionambrinoc/oxhack

I know how to run android apps. Just run it on Android Eclipse, and it works as I expected. It sends the messages to the twilio backend. I got the project from github, and I want to try it, but their twilio IDs expired. So I got a new twilio account, and I tried to replace their ids with mine. And I assumed that App SIDs are the same as App Secret Keys. (Are they?)

I tried to run my code with `python hello.py` on terminal but I got this HUGE error.

`TypeError
TypeError: expected string or buffer
...
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error...
You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:
         dump() shows all variables in the frame
         dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object`

I also have some questions about my code. I put the questions in comments in my python code. Questions are in CAPS

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import twilio.twiml
import requests
import json
import httplib

account_sid = "SOME_ACCOUNT_SID"
auth_token  = "SOME_AUTH_TOKEN"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?
def index():
    phonenumber = request.values.get('From', None)
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    print(body)
    action = json.loads(body)
    current = action['current']
    desired = action['desired']
    lang = action['lang']
    payload={'current':current,'desired':desired,'lang':lang}
    url='http://school/index.php' #The dev used this link. WHAT DOES IT MEAN?
    r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
    print(payload)
    print(r.text)
    response=r.text
    message = client.messages.create(body=response,
                            to=phonenumber,
                            from_="+1408MYTWILIO")
    return message.sid
# IS THE APP SID SAME AS APP SECRET KEY?
app.secret_key = 'MY_APP_SECRET_KEY'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you can answer any of these questions, your help will be greatly appreciate. As I am still learning, and I really want to see how this hackathon project works.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can explain some of what is going on there, but probably not all of it I'm afraid.

Firstly:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?
```

This is a decorator function in python. In the context of this application it applies to the method below `def index():`. It means that when the Flask application receives a `GET` or `POST` request to `'/'` (the root path) it will execute the `index` method.

```
# IS THE APP SID SAME AS APP SECRET KEY?
app.secret_key = 'MY_APP_SECRET_KEY'
```

The secret key for the application is not any of the credentials you get from Twilio. The secret key should be a long random string. It is used with sessions in Flask and the secret key is used to sign the session cryptographically. There is more information on this in the [Flask documentation on settings](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions).

The following lines however:

```
payload={'current':current,'desired':desired,'lang':lang}
url='http://school/index.php' #The dev used this link. WHAT DOES IT MEAN?
r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
```

including the odd `http://school/index.php`, I can't really explain. What I do know is that the hack used the [Esri API](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/) to find directions between two points. It looks as though this section is trying to do that. I have no idea what was behind that URL for the team, it looks as though it may have been some sort of proxy. In order to get this running again, you may need to look through the [Esri API documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/) and find out how to get the text description for a route between two places. If you need help with that, I suggest you give [James Milner](https://twitter.com/jameslmilner), Esri developer evangelist, a shout.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is just a twilio question in general. How would I be able to reply to the user with a customized reply. Just say the user wrote "Exit", how would I be able to read the message and reply with "Ok, we will not message you anymore"?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear they are passing in the original location (current = action['current']), the target destination (desired = action['desired']) and the language (lang = action['lang']).

This would almost certainly be passed to the [ArcGIS routing REST service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/02r3/02r300000054000000.htm) in index.php. Essentially it's and X,Y pair and another X,Y pair in WGS84 coordinates as an input. WGS84 coordinates is just a fancy way of saying conventional GPS longitude and latitude. Take particular notice of the order though, longitude(X) then latitude (Y), as this throws a lot of people.

If you wanted it wouldn't be too much hassle to write the request direct into the app without calling any external scripts (i.e. index.php). If you are using requests the endpoint URL is:

http://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World/solve?

Where you would require the following as your request parameters:

- directionsLanguage=lang
- returnDirections=true
- stops=x1,y1,x2,y2
- token=INSERT_YOUR_ARCGIS_TOKEN_HERE
- f=json

The stops coordinates you would get from current (x1, y1) and desired (x2, y2). The token would come from your [ArcGIS Developer account](http://developers.arcgis.com). f=json just sets the return format to JSON instead of HTML.

Your code may end up looking something like this:

```
payload= {'stops':str(current[0],current[1],desired[0],desired[1]),
          'directionsLanguage':lang, 'returnDirections': "true", 
          'f':'json','token': VAR_WITH_ARCGIS_TOKEN } 
url= 'http://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World/solve?'
```

You there need to concatenate your the directions from your response. You would access these by getting the *directions* array from your response body and then iterating through the features array, concatenating the *text* property of the attributes object.

Hope this clarifies. Leave a comment if you have questions